# Ionic using Page in Page and Setting Attributes

Tags: html, angular, ionic4

I have a question using a page in another. First of all I created the first Page called Header. My Header Page got the Selector:page-Header. Using the Page with this selector in another works fine. But now I created in the header.ts an attribute called "Title". Title is something I also use in the header.html just to show the text. 
Now I want to use the Header again in a second page and set the "Title" attribute but I don't know how. Setting it just in the HTML doesn't work.

Second HTML:

```html
<page-header Title="CrazyNewTitle"></page-header>
```

header.html:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon color="dark" name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button end>
        <ion-icon color="dark" name="contact"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

header.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

/**
 * Generated class for the HeaderPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-header',
  templateUrl: 'header.html',
})
export class HeaderPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

public Title : string;

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HeaderPage');
  }

}
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create get and set method in your header page and your header page will be something like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-header',
  templateUrl: './custom-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-header.component.css']
})
export class CustomHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
title : string;
  constructor() { }
@Input()
  set header(header_data: any) {
    this.title = header_data;
  }
  get header() {
    return this.title;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

After this you have to pass value from parent component to do that create a variable and assign your Header text like:

```
public title = "My Title";
```

And use this string variable name for pass your value so your UI code will be:

```
<app-custom-header [header]="title"></app-custom-header>
```

with this method you can also pass object, array and many more. I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-header123) for your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I unterstand this but doing this I get the error: 
Can't bind to 'header' since it isn't a known property of 'page-header'.
Did I miss something?

Comment: please check you naming are correct. That 'header' came from @Input get and set method name from header page component so it should be same as get set method name and make sure that your selector name is same as your element name.

Comment: Please check that stackblitz one and compare with your source code once :)

Comment: Really thanks for the great help dude. I missed the "@Imput"-Attribute above the getter. 
Works now. :)